# Converting from EnumSet<A> to Set<B> when A inherits from B

Tags: java, enums, enumset

The title pretty much explains the question. I have an interface method:

```
Set<Field> getFieldSet()
```

and I have a class, `User` which looks something like this

```
class User {
    enum Fields implements Field {
        USERNAME, PASSWORD;
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Now I want to implement `User`'s `getFieldSet()` method. The naive way seems to just `return EnumSet.allOf(Fields.class)` but I get the following error:

```
> Type mismatch: cannot convert from Set<User.Fields> to Set<Field>
```

Other than manually copying the EnumSet to `Set<Field>`, is there a good way to do this?

Comment: Can't you just cast it to `Set<Field>`?

Comment: @Alex: No, that's not allowed in Java. If you *could* do that then it could lead to problems, for example: `Set<Object> o = new HashSet<Integer>(); o.add("I'm not an integer");`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could return `new HashSet<Field>(EnumSet.allOf(Fields.class));`.

That will get around the fact that you can't assign a value of type `Set<User.Fields>` to a variable of type `Set<Field>`.

Alternatively, your interface could be `Set<? extends Field> getFields()` instead. You *can* assign `Set<User.Field>` to a capturing variable.

Comment: Note that constructing a new HashSet will cause the set entries to get copied, which removes the performance benefit of using an EnumSet in the first place.

Comment: Yup. Your answer is better :)

Comment: Returning wildcard types from APIs is generally discouraged: it adds complexity to classes calling the API. Probably better to just return a `Set<Field>`.

Comment: @Daniel: I agree. It does make things more complex, but in some cases it's still useful. I mentioned it only because it is a *possible* solution depending on the OPs overall design.

Comment: Good point. It does seem like it's a better idea for SPIs, to make interfaces more flexible, so that the implementation provider to return whatever they want.

Answer (score 3):

Use [Collections.unmodifiableSet](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableSet%28java.util.Set%29):

```
return Collections.<Field>unmodifiableSet(EnumSet.allOf(Fields.class));
```

Pros:

- No unsafe conversion cast: the operation is typesafe at runtime
- The returned set is actually a `Set<Field>`, not a `Set<? extends Field>`
- The set isn't copied, only wrapped
- The returned set cannot be mutated

Cons:

- The returned set cannot be mutated, but it wouldn't be safe to do so anyway.

Answer (score 1):

The reason this doesn't work is that `Set<Fields>` isn't a subtype of `Set<Field>`. For example, if you returned a `Set<Fields>` from your method, you could get a situation like the following:

```
Set<Field> fieldSet = user.getFieldSet(); //Returns an EnumSet<Fields>
fieldSet.add(new Field(){}); //Would compile, but would blow up at runtime, 
                             //because the set can only contain Fields enum 
                             //constants
```

Your best option here is to use a different set implementation (usually an unmodifiable set) to return the values. For example:

```
Set<Field> getFieldSet() {
    return Collections.unmodifiableSet(EnumSet.allOf(Fields.class));
}
```

or, if you need the set to be mutable (probably not a good idea, usually)

```
Set<Field> getFieldSet() {
    return new HashSet(EnumSet.allOf(Fields.class));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is I think a good solution. It's not exactly what you want but close enough

```
import java.util.EnumSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class User {
    enum Fields implements Field {
        USERNAME,
        PASSWORD;
    }

    Set< ? extends Field> getFieldSet() {
        return EnumSet.allOf(Fields.class);
    }
}
```